# How to get the distribution and its parameter from a sympy random variable

Tags: python, sympy

I have created a random variable using sympy like this:

```py
import sympy.stats as stats
x = stats.Normal('X', 0, 1)
```

Now I would like to get back the type of distribution and the parameters from `x`.

I have found that the following code will get back what I expect, but it seems to me that the information is a bit too hidden to be a good or official way of doing this.

```py
distribution = x.pspace.args[1]
mean = distribution.mean
std = distribution.std
```

Does anyone know of a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid args with:

```
In [10]: x.pspace.distribution                                                                                                                                
Out[10]: NormalDistribution(0, 1)

In [11]: x = Normal('X', 0, 1)                                                                                                                                

In [12]: x.pspace.distribution                                                                                                                                
Out[12]: NormalDistribution(0, 1)

In [13]: x.pspace.distribution.std                                                                                                                            
Out[13]: 1

In [14]: x.pspace.distribution.mean                                                                                                                           
Out[14]: 0
```

In general you will need to to check the type of the distribution before trying attributes like `std` and `mean`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is better! It also works in a consistent way for different distributions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, even in the [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/_modules/sympy/stats/rv.html) they access the parameters in this way. There don't seem to be better roads.

However, you can do everything on one line:

```
mean, std = x.pspace.args[1].mean, x.pspace.args[1].std
```